# Reverse for 'calendarDetail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'slug': u'Test-12014-05-05'}' not found

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-urls

I am still trying to understand how url matching and reverse() and get_absolute_url() work. I think I am almost there...

I'm not quite sure why the pattern doesn't match the thing I am reversing. Also, I don't quite get why the regex (?P\w+) doesn't match the slug with hyphens in it. Maybe this has something to do with why it won't reverse properly? It matches using .+ but not \w+.

What is really stopping me is when I try to reverse the following url pattern:

```
url(r'^calendarDetail/(?P<slug>.+)/$', 'phoenixEvents.views.calendarDetail', name='pEventsCalendarDetail'),
```

I get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /calendar
Reverse for 'pEventsCalendarDetail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'slug': u'Test-12014-05-05'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/calendar
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'pEventsCalendarDetail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'slug': u'Test-12014-05-05'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 429
Python Executable:  /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
Python Version: 2.7.6
```

using the following models.py excerpt:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Event(models.Model):
    eventName = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    eventDescription = models.TextField()
    eventDate = models.DateField()
    eventTime = models.TimeField()
    eventLocation = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    creationDate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    eventURL = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=lambda instance: instance.eventName + str(instance.eventDate),
                         unique_with=['eventDate'],
                         slugify=lambda value: value.replace(' ','-'))

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
        path = reverse('pEventsCalendarDetail', (), kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
        return "http://%s" % (path)
```

The complete urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^home$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^calendar$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.calendar', name='calendar'),
    url(r'^forum$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.forum', name='forum'),
    url(r'^donate$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.donate', name='donate'),
    url(r'^donate_thanks$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.donate_thanks', name='donate_thanks'),
    url(r'^what_is_fll$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.what_is_fll', name='what_is_fll'),
    url(r'^core_values$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.core_values', name='core_values'),
    url(r'^follow_the_phoenix$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.follow_the_phoenix', name='follow_the_phoenix'),
    url(r'^followEnter/$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.followEnter', name='followEnter'),
    url(r'^followList/$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.followList', name='followList'),
    url(r'^about_us$', 'electricphoenixfll.views.about_us', name='about_us'),
    #url(r'^calendarDetail/(?P<slug>\w+)/$', 'phoenixEvents.views.calendarDetail', name='pEventsCalendarDetail'),
    url(r'^calendarDetail/(?P<slug>.+)/$', 'phoenixEvents.views.calendarDetail', name='pEventsCalendarDetail'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: Are you sure the application URL's are added into main `urls.py` file?

Comment: For better or worse (probably the latter) I am only using one urls.py file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\w` just covers alphanumeric characters and underscores. The hyphen isn't included in that. Try the following:

```
url(r'^calendarDetail/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'phoenixEvents.views.calendarDetail', name='pEventsCalendarDetail'),
```

Comment: Thanks, I just saw that somewhere and was going to try it, since I tried /w- and that didn't work, maybe this will!

Comment: I don't think your urls files are being included. The exception says ```0 pattern(s) tried: []```. Please edit your question to include more of your urls files.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too. Odd though, because all of the other pages work properly... I've added the complete urls.py file to the post. There aren't any urls in any other file.

Comment: I've tried the pattern in a python shell and it works just fine. I can only conclude from this that it **isn't** the pattern that is the problem. Could this be some kind of bug in Django?
>>> url=re.compile(r'^calendarDetail/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$')
>>> print url.match("calendarDetail/Test-12014-05-05/")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x103b04a80>
>>>